# Prove: A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable if and only if $m(E) = m^\ast (F) + m^\ast (E-F)$

Tags: real-analysis

That is one of our Real Analysis problems.

E is Lebesgue-measurable set on $\mathbb{R}$;$m$ is Lebesgue measure;$m^\ast$ is outer measure which is induced by $m$.

I want to show that if $m(E)<+\infty,F\subseteq E$,  then:

$F$ is measurable $\iff$ $m(E)=m^\ast (F) + m^\ast (E-F)$.

The forward proof is easy, but i can't work out the backward.

Any help would be nice to me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Note that $m^{*}(F)= \inf_{A\supset F} m(A)$.

Define also the interior measure
$$m_{*}(F) = \sup_{A\subset F} m(A)$$

Now check that if $E$ measurable, $m(E)<\infty$, and $F\subset E$, then
$$ m(E)=m_{*}(F) + m^{*}(E\backslash F) $$

Now check that if 
$$m_{*}(F) = m^{*}(F) < \infty$$ then $F$ is measurable

Comment: Wow! That's cooool. I never thought of inner measure! I think i can work it out :)